# Is G Suite as a SAML IdP a replacement for Okta?

Tags: authentication, google, single-sign-on, saml

G Suite supports [acting as the identity provider](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en) to SAML-compatible service providers, in the same way as [Okta does](https://developer.okta.com/standards/SAML/setting_up_a_saml_application_in_okta).

However, you pay a premium for Okta whereas Google SAML is included in the G Suite bundle.

When logging into SAML-authenticated apps, does Okta offer something which G Suite doesn't?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but don't you pay for G Suite as well?

Comment: @bviktor correct, we do – but we're paying for that anyway (for mail, calendar, docs, meetings, …)

Comment: I think Okta is more extensible (maybe?) and they offer command line tooling that you dont get out of the box from gsuite